# Vertex group names don't change along with renamed bones

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups

Usually when I change the name of a bone on an armature, the name of the corresponding vertex group changes to match the bone name. However, I've run into some instances where this automatic change doesn't happen. I checked the mesh and it was parented to the armature and has the armature modifier set up. The only thing I could think of that caused the issue would be that I renamed the armature. Is that the issue or is something else the culprit?

Comment: Hello could you please share an object and its armature you have the problem with?

Comment: I would check for any duplicate vertex group names.  It may be renaming one VG but not the other.  Renaming bones can create these duplicate VG names; it's a current issue on the tracker.